# how i can Drop Files Into maui app from desktop?

Tags: c#, maui, desktop

"To drag a file from the desktop to the MAUI app, you need to use the Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DropGestureRecognizer class and handle file-type data. However, at the moment there is a bug that prevents receiving file data from Windows Explorer¹. This bug should be fixed in future versions of MAUI."

it's true? there is a bug?

i would like use this app for windows and macos, Desktop app.

Comment: where did you get that quote from?  Please link to a source so we have some idea what you are talking about.  And that appears to refer specifically to Windows, but you later mention Mac OS.  Which platform are you concerned with?

Comment: .net Maui is a framework cross platform. I don’t need mobile jet. 
Source code, at this time, isn’t important… I haven’t wrong code. I don’t know what import ad which class I must used.      Thank you!

Comment: I know MAUI is cross platform.  You haven’t answered either of the questions I asked

Comment: The Open Maui issue for this: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6080. There is no workaround listed. Therefore, this cannot be done at this time. All you can do is watch that issue for an update.

Comment: @jason I'm sorry. I didn't understand the question. Having found nothing here, on different forums, on official documentation, I asked "Bing Chat".

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you! I'll wait or look for some other framework, maybe flutter.